# how to create automatically an object inside an array each time the user fill 3 inputs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop

each time the user fill the first name and last name and the adress inputs the script will take these values and put theme inside the first object who will contain 3 proprieties

```
    FirstName = FirstName.value;
    LastName = LastName.value;
    Adress = Adress.value;
```

and when the user want to add a new contact, these new values must not replace the old ones that they already inside the first object, the new values must be on a new object, and keep doing that each time the user fills the 3 inputs

so my question is how to do that?

Comment: What have you tried and didn't work out? Show people your work and ask for help. Handing out tasks to people and expecting free solution should be the point of stackoverflow.

Comment: take here is all what i have done without any result 

(https://www.dropbox.com/sh/cnoek6ekbivya5k/AACI2aX3VPgseCELbTspKdCEa?dl=0)

Comment: Check it out https://jsbin.com/codoxesuyo/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 0):

You can use Global Array

> var data = [];

Assign the values to that array once the values are changed.

At the time of submit check that value already in Array.

```
function ExistsInarray(array, value) {
    for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
        if(array[i][0].id === value)
      {
       value already there...
      }
      else
       return true;
    }
```

Comment: But inside that array i want to script to add an object each time the user fills the inputs 

i want to see on the end 
var contacts = [{firstName: "first name value1",
lastName:"last name 1",
adress : "adress 1"
"} ]

and when the user before refreshing the page adds a new contact i want to see 

var contacts = [{firstName: "first name value1",
lastName:"last name 1",
adress : "adress 1"
"},
{firstName: "first name value2",
lastName:"last name 2",
adress : "adress 2"
"} ]

Comment: Then you add these vales to dictionary object. key and value pair. refer this link..
var dict = []; // create an empty array

dict.push({
    key:   "value1",
    value: "firstname,lastname,address"
});
dict.push({
    key:   "value2",
    value: "firstname,lastname,address"
});

Answer (score 0):

You could create new instance of `Person` each time user press submit button and store it in array, but you still need to store this somewhere

```js
var Person = function(firstName, lastName, adress) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
  this.adress = adress;
}

var persons = [];

$('#submit').click(function() {
  var first_name = $('#firstName').val();
  var last_name = $('#lastName').val();
  var adress = $('#adress').val();

  if (first_name != '' && last_name != '' && adress != '') {
    persons.push(new Person(first_name, last_name, adress));
  }
  console.log(persons);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="firstName">
<input type="text" id="lastName">
<input type="text" id="adress">
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a JS script holding all of that, but if you want to hold your data after you'll need to implement a persistence provider (file on server side, Database, etc) :

```
var array[];
```

It is important that this array should not be instanciated in the following code, but use it at global scope, to make it easier.

then declare a function executed at start, and :

```
var button = $('#buttonAddContact');
button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var obj = new Contact(); // fill it now
    array.append(obj);
});
```

this is in pseudo code, but it will give you the algorithm.
In the array you'll have all contacts added by the user for current sessions.

(and you'll have to adapt it if you're not using jQuery for example)